# how to target haskell to android using jhc?

Tags: haskell, android-ndk, ghc

I want to write a Haskell function (module) of type: `String -> String` to call in Android. The easiest method seems to use JHC to generate C code, then use Android NDK to generate a shared library, but I could not find any documentation for JHC. Does JHC also use Cabal to build? Is JHC stable enough to use Parsec or Attoparsec library?

Comment: The easiest method is probably Frege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in 2011 I had limited success using JHC in a similar way, but targeting iOS instead of Android. [Initial results were good](https://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2011-02-13-developing_iphone_applications_in_haskell___a_tutorial/) in just getting the thing running, but we ended up discarding JHC in favor of GHC precisely because we started getting weird compile-time errors on programs that used Parsec. Bear in mind, this was in 2011 so JHC might have improved by a lot since.

If you want to give GHC a chance, I'd recommend [looking at this example](https://github.com/sseefried/docker-epidemic-build-env) which uses GHC 7.8 to compile a game for Android. I haven't used it in anger yet, but I did manage to get it working on Docker, getting as far as rebuilding the game from scratch and installing it on a real Android device, so the approach definitely has merit.

**UPDATE as of August 2017:** Moritz Angermann has posted [detailed instructions on targeting Android with a GHC  cross-compiler](https://medium.com/@zw3rk/a-haskell-cross-compiler-for-android-8e297cb74e8a).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I posted the bounty I was hoping for recent attempts, exactly because I didn't see anyone using JHC for this since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Well [a compiler called eta](http://eta-lang.org/) maybe the most convenient way now.it targets jvm and it will produce a jar file so you can directly put it in your project